# communication with USB Serial device over the web

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, usb

I have been searching for a way to communicate with our USB device (an NFC reader), the user should not have to install anything (some of our companies do not allow their employs to install anything on their computers besides the programs that are already installed).

**option 1**: chrome.serial (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial)
chrome.serial is I think a good choice but it is being phased out within the next year or two, as described here: http://www.omgchrome.com/not-joke-google-killing-chrome-apps/

**option 2**: I have found was WebUSB API (https://wicg.github.io/webusb/)

But it requires an addition to the firmware, which we can do, and WebUSB API looks like the best option right now.

**other options(not viable options)**:
- Silverlight (dead. supported till 2021) 
- ActiveX (Only works on IE, security setting needs changing, certificates, etc, etc) 
- Windows service/Form? (only works on windows, requires install)

So **my question** is, is there any other ways of communicating with our serial via the web? possibly similar to chrome.serial or WebUSB API but without the firmware change?

Comment: Another is to write a plugin which is running in the OS background. It will access USB resource and send back whatever you need to your web application. Then your web application will interact with client. Kind of complex solution.

Comment: For those coming to this question in 2020, Arduino created the arduino-create-agent software to expose the local devices over websockets: https://github.com/arduino/arduino-create-agent
Currently trying to make Serial work over WebUSB, but so far no luck.